# O que são objetos anônimos em Java?

Tags: java

Alguém pode me dar exemplos de como usar objetos anônimos em java?

Comment: Já leu a resposta da pergunta linkada? Ela explica bem o conceito de classe anonima, que é a mesma coisa. Dá uma olhada la, e edite a pergunta conforme for surgindo duvidas, assim essa deixa de ser duplicata.

Comment: blza, obrigado. Vou analisar melhor.